# Android Game Point Drawing

Tags: java, android, game-engine, point

I am having a problem converting points from world coordinates to screen coordinates. I have a map that has a track which consists of points every 5px or so to draw the track. The map is 2500x2000 and my canvas (phone screen) is 800x600px.

I want to draw only the visible track on the phone screen until the car moves. So I grabbed the points from my point array where (point.x > mapx) and (point.x < mapx + screenWidth) and the same for Y. So this grabbed all the current points of the track that were on the screen.

Now I need to convert these back to screen coordinates to display and this is where I am stuck. For example on the right of the map a point may be 2200x1000 but I can't draw here as the screen is only 800x600.

Any help converting these?

Thanks

Code called from onDraw() method:

```
// loop track array
    Point point;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.trackPoints.size(); i++) {
        point = this.trackPoints.get(i);
        // if that piece of track is on the screen currently then add to
        // array
        if ((point.x > mapx) && (point.x < mapx + this.getWidth())
                && (point.y > mapy) && (point.y < mapy + this.getHeight())) {

            //translate point back to screen-coords
            Log.v("visibletrack", "adding point x = " + point.x + " point y = " + point.y);
            Log.v("visibledebugging", "mapmaxx = " + this.mapMaxX + " mapmaxy = " + this.mapMaxY);
            Log.v("visibledebugging", "scale x = " + scaleX + " scaley = " + scaleY);
            this.visibleTrackPoints.add(new Point((int)(point.x/scaleX), (int)(point.y/scaleY)));
        }
    }
```

The above works I can get the points of the track that should be displaying on the screen but now I need to convert them so they draw in 'big' on the screen. For instance if the map was clipped at 2000,100 and there was a point here then that point should be drawn at 0,100 on the screen. So I need to convert those first coordinates to their correct location on the screen.

Comment: Can you post your code so far please.

Comment: Hi I have added the code, which works as expected. But I need to convert those points as they are on a world scale on not a screen scale thanks

Comment: I think you've answered the question yourself, 'scale' being the optimum word.

Comment: Yes I know this, but this bit I can't figure out hence I'm posting! Is it just a case of if a point is over halfway then scale on +x or if its before half then scale backwards on -x?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what your problem is. If the origins of both your co-ordinate systems coincide then I think it's just a matter of applying the appropriate scaling factor to the co-ordinates in one system to arrive at the scaled coordinates in the other. It the origins of each coordinate system do NOT coincide then you need to also apply a transformation as well as scaling.

Rather than a programming issue I think this is a mathematical one instead.

Comment: Yes I think your right. I end up with the right points but they are very small so I need to scale them in the x and y but this is what I can't figure out. Im guessing it would be x+x/width or something similar but this is where I am stuck?